# Is it possible to create OGC wms service based on the arcgis mxd file and data in java

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

We are trying to create a OGC wms using J2EE, and we know there  are some opensource solution, like geoserver-wms. However most of them will use the `SLD` to render the data to an image. Which does not meet our requirement.

Then I wonder if we can read the `mxd` file in java and generate data according to the wms parameters?

---

Update:

We have arcgis engine license.

Since we are trying to create a OGC WMS servcie, so we will have to generate an image and return it to user.

Comment: It would help if you could more concisely state what your requirement(s) and environment are - I'm assuming your service must generate an image from an existing mxd?  What level of ArcGIS license do you have access to (engine, desktop, server)?  I am fairly confident that you will need some level of ArcGIS license to read and do stuff with the mxd.

Comment: @user890: I update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that without some level of ArcGIS Server license, accessing the mxd in any type of web context will not be possible (or legal).

There are tools out there that can use mxds as the basis for WMS styling/symbolization.  One such tool is [MXD2map](http://mxd2map.org/about.html), that converts ArcGIS MXD-files into UMN MapServer Mapfiles.  With no intentions to start a flame war here - UMN MapServer makes a far superior WMS server than
anything ESRI has to offer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I wonder if we can use the UMN MapServer mapfiles in our J2EE appliation?

Comment: Its possible, start with something like: http://mapserver.org/ogc/mapscript.html#java-example

Comment: So it seems that if I create a WMS Service using J2EE application, then this application will work as an proxy, it will call the `Map Server` in turn according to the parameters from the client, then return what it got from `Map Server` to the client?

Comment: That's how I'd do it - don't think there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to get Bridge, which will allow you to export your maps directly to GeoServer (and eventually to GeoNetwork).  http://geocat.net/bridge